# parameter incorrect in private key error

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, private-key

I have private and public key in separate files.

in instruction says use this code:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

rsa.FromXmlString(PrivateKey);
```

but when the code reaches at second line I get this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.

what's the problem?

in sample code from company which we've got the key, it uses a sample peivate and public key like this:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>KEY VALUE</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

Even though I join `<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>` to the start and `</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>`

to the end, notting works

Comment: Can you show an example private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this site to convert my key from pure string to xml:

https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter

Because .Net want keys in xml format

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes, and I want any code in C# that convert my key to xml and vice versa like the site above

Comment: The site you've linked to in your answer contains the complete code for that. If you scroll down on that page, there is a link to a gist.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I didin't notice that. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that your private key doesn't have all of the D, P, Q, DP, DQ, InverseQ values.

The next most likely cause is that your D, in byte[] form, isn't as long as Modulus (in byte[] form). On that same vein, P/Q/DP/DQ/InverseQ all need to have their byte[] form as half of the length of Modulus (round up).

There are certain keys for which this isn't true in the XML format. The most reliable way is to build the RSAParameters structure yourself and call `ImportParameters`. One reason: the XML methods aren't available in .NET Core at all, but ImportParameters is.